# Should I consider/use what Entity Framework persist as a reading model to my UI?

Tags: entity-framework, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am making a sample .NET application implementing CQRS & Event Sourcing in the ground.
I am using Entity Framework to persist my domain to a SQL Server database and the Events serialized to Json document.

But it same that I don't quit understand two thing;

- Should I consider/use what Entity Framework persist to SQL Server as a reading model to my UI ?
- Does the Read and Write models uses the same domain entities ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I consider/use what Entity Framework persist to SQL Server as a
>   reading model to my UI ?

You can use SQL Server for the read-side, but if your UI relies on hierarchial JSON data, a document-oriented approach like NoSQL might be the better storage.

**UPDATE**, besides that, consider that read-side models might be changed quite often. Events might be transformed into multiple representations. A new frontend feature might introduce a new view on a certain set of data. If you always have to keep up with schemas and ORM mappings, things get harder. In a NoSQL database, putting arbitrary data is much easier as no schema definition is needed.

> Does the Read and Write models uses the same domain entities ?

No, CQRS gives you the ability to use different models on the read-side and write-side. And both read and write operations can be optimized independently. That is all CQRS is about. For example, on the read side you do not have to bother with validation, normalization and integrity, because the state simply cannot be changed. If you use same models, you lose that advantage.

Comment: So, I can keep using an ORM to persist my domain in SQL Server and query/read the same persisted domain without the ORM, implementing differents optimised models?

Comment: Well you can use the same _technology_. Your read-model could be based on SQL VIEWS for example. It hardly makes sense to use the same "persisted domain".